# Trying to find a attribute that contains and then match the number

Tags: jquery, html, contains

Trying to find an attribute that contains "launch-overlay-", so even there are other classes before and after, the scrip will still work. After finding it, add the "active" class to the match number div. This is what I have so far, but if there other class around the "launch-overlay-", it won't work. ><
Help plz.

```js
$('div[class*="overlay-"]').click(function(){
  var overlaynum = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0];
  $('.overlay-container-'+overlaynum).addClass('-active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=“other-class overlay-1”>click me</div>
<div class=“other-class overlay-2”>click me</div>

<div class=“overlay-container-1”></div>
<div class=“overlay-container-2”></div>
```

Comment: not exists element with `launch-` class prefix

Comment: using a data attribute would make much more sense

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in HTML attributes. Use either `'` or `"`

Comment: When you're editing code, make sure you turn off "smart quotes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a capture group to get the overlay number only when it appears after `launch-overlay-`:

```
var overlaynum = this.className.match(/launch-overlay-(\d+)/)[1];
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^−−− capture group 1
```

Note that I get the number via `[1]` instead of `[0]` since it's the first capture group (we don't want the full match that's in `[0]`).

Live Example (I've had to fix a couple of things in there, but they don't seem related to the question):

```js
$('div[class*="launch-overlay-"]').click(function(){
  // Get the number from the relevant class
  var overlaynum = this.className.match(/launch-overlay-(\d+)/)[1];
  $('.overlay-container-'+overlaynum).addClass('-active');
});
```

```css
.-active {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="other-class launch-overlay-1 other">click me - I have another class</div>
<div class="other-class launch-overlay-2">click me</div>

<div class="overlay-container-1">overlay container 1</div>
<div class="overlay-container-2">overlay container 2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is you are not selecting the id, you are selecting the whole match. Use capture group.

var overlaynum = $(this).attr('class').match(/overlay-1(\d+)/)[0];

But personally I would not even use reg exp with matching classes. Use a data attribute.

```js
$("[data-toggles]").on("click", function () {
  var selector = $(this).data("toggles")
  $(selector).toggleClass("active")
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="other-class" data-toggles=".overlay-container-1">click me</div>
<div class="other-class" data-toggles=".overlay-container-2">click me</div>

<div class="overlay-container-1">X</div>
<div class="overlay-container-2">Y</div>
```